# TFS remains out of sync after Get Sources step

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

[image]We migrated to TFS 2015 RTM recently and were successful in creating build pools, configuring build agents and build definitions.

During the build process, TFS performs Get Sources task and successfully completes the same and marks itself in green.

The problem begins here wherein the build process does not download the entire set of files and folders, picks few folders and downloads them completely and ignores the rest.
We have set Clean option to True in the Repository tab of our build definition. Also have marked the files as mapped.

Any help or suggestions in resolving this issue would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
> 2015-12-17T11:51:44.4623378Z Starting: Get sources
2015-12-17T11:51:44.4779612Z Clean is set to true. Removing all repository folders.
2015-12-17T11:53:38.9214724Z Entering TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2015-12-17T11:53:38.9214724Z localPath=E:\agent\_work\9cf6b32b\Platform
2015-12-17T11:53:38.9214724Z clean=True
2015-12-17T11:53:38.9214724Z sourceVersion=C8496
2015-12-17T11:53:38.9214724Z mappingJson={"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/Platform/Kernel/Release/350/src/Build","mappingType":"map"}]}
2015-12-17T11:53:38.9214724Z Syncing repository: Platform (TFVC)
2015-12-17T11:53:38.9214724Z workspaceName=ws_9cf6b32b_7
2015-12-17T11:53:46.6600633Z Workspace Name: ws_9cf6b32b_7;
2015-12-17T11:53:49.4179203Z Done syncing repository Platform to version C8496 (workspace version -1)
2015-12-17T11:53:49.4179203Z Leaving TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
```

Comment: Have you checked the repository tab on the build definition and under Mappings - make sure all the files you need are mapped (and not cloaked).  That is what is going to determine what gets pulled down to the build agent.

Comment: @rerwinRR We have marked the the files as mapped and not as cloaked.

Comment: Would you be able to add screenshots of your configuration?

Comment: @MrHinsh Have added the screen shot of the configuration.

Comment: Can you post the logs of the first build step (Get Sources)?

Comment: @ds19 Please find the logs:

Comment: @Santhosh, 1). did you simplify the log you posted above (deleting entries like "Getting path\filename;C2")? 2). Can you also include the error message you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log:

> 2015-12-17T11:53:49.4179203Z Done syncing repository Platform toversion C8496 (**workspace version -1**)

This seems to be a security related issue.

Please make sure "Project Collection Build Service" has the permission to access to your code folder. Refer to [this article](http://blog.majcica.com/2015/12/24/tfs-2015-build-agent-failing-syncing-the-repository/) for details.

Comment: We were able to resolve this issue by adding the user account under which the build agent was configured to Project Collection Valid users group in TFS 2015.